# Is there a way to make an admin dashboard that can track android device in real time using React Native or Java and React?

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, tracking

everyone.

I'm developing an app for android phone tracking and I need to make an admin dashboard with the ability to track android device in real time and generate reports, how can I do that with Java or React Native and React as web framework.

I tried searching for it ready to use functions but got really lost and confused